# Allow a class object "Weapon" to be an attribute of another class object "Player"

Tags: c++, visual-studio, class

I am working on a small, text-based game for a school project. Essentially what I am trying to do is have a class "Player" use "Armor" or "Weapon classes as attributes, to simulate "equipping" them. Players will have basic attributes like HP, Strength, Defense. I'll also use Attack/Defense based on those attributes, combined with a bonus from weapons/armor.

I would also like to have "Armor" and "Weapon" classes, which would give a bonus. For instance, a sword object of class Weapon would give +5 attack to the player's strength, say 3. So, the character's attack would be 3 +5 = 8.

However, I can't quite figure out how to get the "Weapon" data type to be an attribute of the "Player" class.

I am using Visual Studio 2022 and getting the following errors:

Error   C3646   'equippedWeapon': unknown override specifier

Error   C4430   missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int

```
#include <iostream>

class Character {
public:
    std::string name;
    int level;
}; // END Character class

// ==============================================
// Player Class
// ==============================================

class Player : public Character {
private:
    // Base Attributes
    int maxHealth;
    int strength;
    int stamina;
    int speed;

    // Battle Attributes
    int attack;
    int defense;

    // Position Data
    int xPosition;
    int yPosition;

public:
    Weapon equippedWeapon;
};

class Weapon {
private:
    int attackBonus;
public:
    //Public Attributes
    friend class Player;
    std::string name;

    // Constructor
    Weapon(std::string name, int x) {
        attackBonus = x;
        name = name;
    }

    // Member Functions
    int get_attack_bonus() {
        int bonusValue = attackBonus;
        return attackBonus;
    }
};

Weapon broadSword("Broad Sword", 3);

int main()
{
    std::cout << "This is my main function" << std::endl;

    Player Player1;
    Player1.name = "Mister Man";
    Player1.level = 1;

    return 0;
}
```

I guess, "can" I use a class as an attribute to another class in this way?

Comment: Generally "items" are not attributes of a character, in the RPG sense.

Comment: As for your problem, you do remember what your beginners teaching material said about all symbols needing to be declared or defined *before* they are used? Think about the order in which you declare or define your classes.

Comment: It's most certainly not an "attribute", but for the sake of keeping things extremely simple until I get the core program running, I am making it so. 

Thank you for the point in the right direction! I tried a forward declaration, but it left me with an error for it being still undefined, so I had to fully define Weapon before defining Player. 

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: If you create an *object* of a class, you need the full definition of the class. If you create a reference or a pointer to an object, then you only need the declaration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider this: Your player has a weapon; the weapon should not have a player.

I very quickly edited your code so it would run but you may need to tweak it:

```
class Weapon {
private:
    int attackBonus;
public:
    //Public Attributes
    // Constructor
    Weapon() {
    }

    // Member Functions
    int get_attack_bonus() {
        int bonusValue = attackBonus;
        return attackBonus;
    }
};

class Player : public Character {
private:
    // Base Attributes
    int maxHealth;
    int strength;
    int stamina;
    int speed;

    // Battle Attributes
    int attack;
    int defense;

    // Position Data
    int xPosition;
    int yPosition;

public:
    Weapon equippedWeapon;
};



int main()
{
    std::cout << "This is my main function" << std::endl;

    Player Player1;
    Player1.name = "Mister Man";
    Player1.level = 1;

    return 0;
}
```